# How Can I Refactor These Assertions To Avoid Duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring, shoulda

Is there a way to refactor this to avoid the repetition of:

```
post :create, user: attributes_for(:user)
```

Given that the first assertion needs to wrap it in an `expect` block, I don't see a way of moving it to a `before` block. Obviously I could wrap the last two assertions in a `context` or `describe` block with its own `before` block, but this doesn't feel right.

```
   context 'with valid attributes' do

    it 'should create a new User and save it to the database' do
      expect {
        post :create, user: attributes_for(:user)
      }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end

    it {
      post :create, user: attributes_for(:user)
      should redirect_to(user_path(assigns[:user]))
    }

    it {
      post :create, user: attributes_for(:user)
      should set_the_flash[:notice]
    }

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your "action" in a method, as follows:

```
context 'with valid attributes' do
  it 'should create a new User and save it to the database' do
    expect {
      do_action
    }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end

  it {
    do_action
    should redirect_to(user_path(assigns[:user]))
  }

  it {
    do_action
    should set_the_flash[:notice]
  }

  def do_action
    post :create, user: attributes_for(:user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not make sure that it works)

```
  context 'with valid attributes' do
    before { post :create, user: attributes_for(:user) }

    it 'should create a new User and save it to the database' do
      expect(User.count).to eq 1
    end

    it { should redirect_to(user_path(assigns[:user])) }
    it { should set_the_flash[:notice] }
  end
```